# Algorithm to get all possible combination of 3 numbers that add up to 100 in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

Each number should be greater than 0.
Order doesn't matter. For example: the values can be 25, 50, 25 or 25, 25, 50 or 50, 25, 25.
Maybe we could use Random class and generate 3 int values, each less than 99 and greater than 0 and then add the 3 numbers. If the addition equals 100 print the 3 numbers.
Is there a better way, or should I just use the above method?

edit: I'm trying to solve this: https://curiosity.com/topics/can-you-solve-the-cat-fish-bird-riddle-curiosity/

I plan to get 3 numbers that add up to 100, and then i'll use those 3 numbers in another method to multiply the first number with 10, the second number with 3 and the last number with 0.5. if the results add up to 100 then i've found the solution. Right?

edit 2.1:
Here's the code I've come up with. It works!

```
    // cat, fish, bird riddle

class RiddleOne {
    private float num, a, b, c, x, y, z;


    public void getBird() {
        for (x = 1; x <= 100; x++) {
            for (y = 1; y <= 100-x; y++) {
                z = 100 - x - y;

                if (checkQuantity()) {
                System.out.print("\n\tThe quantity of cat, fish and bird toys purchased are " +x +", " +y +" and " +z +" respectively.");
                System.out.print("\n\tThe total price of each toy is " +a +", " +b +" and " +c +" respectively.");
                num = a + b + c;
                System.out.print("\n\tThe total price is: " +num);
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean checkQuantity() {
        a = 10 * x;
        b = 3 * y;
        c = z / 2;

        if (((a + b + c) == 100) && c != 0) 
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RiddleOne t = new RiddleOne();
        t.getBird();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this some homework?

Comment: That method will likely generate many duplicates. How would you stop generating them once you'd hit the last set of numbers if it is all random? It might just be faster to use a nested loop.

Comment: Is this homework, or what is it for? Definitely don't use randomness for this, though; it will cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this by writing a Java program: https://curiosity.com/topics/can-you-solve-the-cat-fish-bird-riddle-curiosity/

Comment: haven't seen the solution for it.

Answer (score 3):

A smart thing to do when order does not matter is to make your algorithm in such a way that for every solution it can only generate a certain order. That way you know you have no duplicates. For instance, I am going to look at sorted order. (which means a <= b <= c)

You would start by generating a, since the other 2 must be higher or equal to a, a must be lower than 100/3 since otherwise b or c must be lower than 100/3.

Then we know about b that it must be at least a, and it must be lower or equal to 100 - a - b and thus also lower or equal to (100 - a)/2.

Our algorithm would then be something like this:

```
public void printAllCombinations() {
    for (int a = 1; a <= 100/3; a++) {
        for (int b = a; b <= (100 - a)/2; b++) {
            int c = 100 - a - b;
            // Report a, b and c
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: won't this limit value of a to be less than 33.3?

Comment: Yes but if it would be higher it wouldn't be in order and thus you would get multiple solutions that are in fact the same solution but in a different order.

Comment: Thats more maths than programming so you're not entirely in the right place here. Also that page gives you an answer already in the video below, I don't really see the use of answering it again here.

Comment: just for fun. I've found the correct solution to it.

Comment: This is not a good algorithm because the OP specifically pointed out that the values could repeat but in different order.

Comment: Then you interpreted what he said differently. As I see it he mentioned these different orderings to indicate that they are seen as the same. Otherwise the fact that he said that ordering does not matter and the term combination would be wrong. But it's not 100% clear what he means.

Answer (score 1):

### Brute force all combinations

Each number is between 1 and 100 (well, 98) so you get 100*100*100 = million combinations by a nested loop across all possible values of each number. Or you can just check out all combinations of two numbers and require the third to be 100-a-b. Since order doesn't matter, you need a way to filter out duplicates.

Using random numbers is not a good solution since you're not guaranteed to get *all* possible combinations, and even if you just continue it long enough to get a reasonable chance of getting all valid combinations, you need much more tries than just trying every combination once.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop over two numbers; let's call them `i` and `j`. Because the numbers need to sum up to 100, then the third number `k` will be known immediately: `k = 100 - i - j`.

Below I've written some code to do just that:

```
public class Sum100 {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j <= 100-i; j++) {
                int k = 100 - i - j;
                System.out.printf("i=%3d, j=%3d, k=%3d\n", i, j, k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below are a few lines out of all the output:

```
i= 38, j= 59, k=  3
i= 38, j= 60, k=  2
i= 38, j= 61, k=  1
i= 38, j= 62, k=  0
i= 39, j= 39, k= 22
i= 39, j= 40, k= 21
i= 39, j= 41, k= 20
```

As you can see, the code can generate values of 0 for any of the variables. Try to fix that so you can better learn what the algorithm is doing.

Follow up questions:

1. Can you predict exactly how many lines will be printed from just looking at the code loops?
2. What is the Big-O running time of this algorithm?

Comment: 2 things wrong with this answer, values should never be 0, and it is about possible combinations, not possible permutations. So a solution that has the same numbers but in a different order should be considered as the same solution. This algorithm would for example generate 50,25,25 and 25,25,50 as two different solutions while they are in fact the same. A quick and easy fix would be to enforce that they are in order.

Comment: 1. 101 2. What's Big-O?

Comment: @DaanvanderKallen: The OP specifically said that numbers could repeat but in different order: `the values can be 25, 50, 25 or 25, 25, 50 or 50, 25, 25`

Comment: @Skaper: 1. Not right. There is a summation involved. 2 "Big-O" running time is an important measure of algorithm complexity, as you may learn in a formal computer science class. Here, the Big-O complexity is O(N^2).

Comment: Thanks for the solution @stackoverflowuser2010, I have just modified your answer as below:
`for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            for (var j = i; j < 100-i; j++) {
                var k = 100 - i - j;
                console.log("banana "+i,"orange "+j,"mango "+ k);
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't use randomness.

The first step is to pick a number `j` between 1 and 33, inclusive, in a loop. Next, pick `k` to be between `j` and `(99-j)/2`, inclusive. Finally, the third number is determined: `100-j-k`. This will give you all possible triplets in ascending order, with values in ascending order, and in faster time than Peteris algorithm.